# Google docs style drupal site

Tags: 7

Ive been searching around drupal and google to find some awnsers but get lost and fustrated and came here for some help.

What i want to do is have a drupal site which is not public, and has the functionality of google docs, calendar and drive...yes i know i could just use what google have already made but im a little paranoid in this world and would like to have TOTAL control over my documents as this will also be on a dedicated server.

So are there modules/ways out there where i can upload/download + edit text documents and spreadsheets? I know i could use a WYSIWYG but could i then download the page/node as a .doc file for example?

Sorry if it doesnt make much sense,
Many Thanks in Advance
Russel

Answer (score 2):

An all in one solution I think is hard to find/make for drupal.
There's a module, where you can import and edit spreadsheets. I've testet it briefly for a project, that never go further than prototyping, but the module simply worked:
http://drupal.org/project/sheetnode

There might be similar projects for word processors. Or you might have it made :)

For a Google drive alternative, where you are in control, have a look at http://owncloud.org. They have calendar, contacts, and many other things, but I don't think they have editors.

Answer (score 1):

Original .doc specification is proprietary, so you need to be big enough company if you want to deal with Microsoft about it. To my best knowledge there are no free, drupal-based clones of Google Docs, Open Office or any other office suite. OpenOffice's source code is about 250MB compressed. Drupal's is around 3.5MB compressed... That should show amount of work ratio nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you found a solution. You might be interested in [depdocs.com](http://depdocs.com/). It's a document management Drupal system that does what you are looking for. It's not as flexible as Google docs but it will get you a long way.

Answer (score 0):

For online document editing, you could integrate [Firepad](http://www.firepad.io/) into Drupal. That won't give you the full Office-style document suite, however, and it stores data using firebase.com - paid service, now free for small traffic but this may change in future.

[Alfresco](http://addons.alfresco.com/addons/edit-online-libreoffice-openoffice) appears to offer something more like what you are after as an addon but of course Alfresco isn't Drupal.